# Linux symbolic links: how to go to the pointed to directory?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, xfce

I have a project in its own directory:

> /dir/to/project/

I have a symbolic link to that directory on the desktop:

> /home/user/Desktop/project/

When I double click on that link, the directory window that opens is:

> /home/user/Desktop/project/

instead of the real one, `/dir/to/project`.

The same happens with the command line (Bash).

Is it possible to get what I wish, i.e. go to the directory pointed to, instead of the symbolic one?

Note: the windows environment I am using now is Xfce, but I am also interested in a generic answer.

Comment: If you want a Windows-like shortcut, use a [.desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2484/what-does-examples-desktop-do)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `bash` the `cd` builtin uses `-P` and `-L` switches; `pwd` understands them in the same way:

```
user@host:~$ ln -s /bin foobar
user@host:~$ cd -L foobar      # follow link
user@host:~/foobar$ pwd -L     # print $PWD
/home/user/foobar
user@host:~/foobar$ pwd -P     # print physical directory
/bin
user@host:~/foobar$ cd -       # return to previous directory
/home/user
user@host:~$ cd -P foobar      # use physical directory structure
user@host:/bin$ pwd -L         # print $PWD
/bin
user@host:/bin$ pwd -P         # print physical directory
/bin
```

Moreover `cd ..` may be tricky:

```
user@host:/bin$ cd
user@host:~$ cd -L foobar
user@host:~/foobar$ cd -L ..   # go up, to ~/
user@host:~$ cd -L foobar
user@host:~/foobar$ cd -P ..   # go up, but not to ~/
user@host:/$
```

See `help cd` and `help pwd`. Note that you may also have an executable (i.e. not a shell builtin) like `/bin/pwd` that should behave similarly. In my Kubuntu the difference is the `pwd` builtin without any option uses `-L` while `/bin/pwd` by default uses `-P`.

You can adjust the default behavior of `cd` builtin by `set -P` (`cd` acts as `cd -P`) and `set +P` (`cd` acts as `cd -L`). See `help set` for details.

Answer (score 7):

Use `readlink` to resolve the link to its target:

```
cd $(readlink thelink)
```

You may want to define a function in your bash profile:

```
function cdl { local dir=$(readlink -e $1); [[ -n "$dir" ]] && cd $dir; }
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Yours is the best approach. If you write it as an answer (with details about how to do the same thing from the GUI), I will tick it as the accepted one.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - OK about GUIs' behaviour. Again, if you rewrite your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to achieve it in GUI, but there is a workaround in Command line.

Say your symbolic link is :

```
/home/user/Desktop/project/
```

then, You can use **[readlink](https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink)** command to get resolved symbolic link or it's canonical file name. Then just `cd` to it.

```
cd `readlink /home/user/Desktop/project`
```

Here, `readlink` resolves the linkname and then passes to `cd` using [substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

If you are already in the Desktop folder, then there is no need to specify absolute path, just `project` will do

```
cd `readlink project`
```

If you visit this folder frequently, you can write a one line function for it in bash :

```
function cdproject
{
    cd `readlink home/user/Desktop/project`;
}
```