# How do I open the file location of a shortcut's target?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, file-shortcut, ubuntu-22.04, thunar

I have a shortcut to a file. This file is inside of a folder. In Thunar, I have the folder that the shortcut itself is in (i.e. not the folder that the shortcut's target is in). I wish to open the folder of the item that the shortcut points to. I was expecting to be able to right-click and get an option like "Open File Location". Is there anything analogous in Thunar?

I've even tried viewing the shortcut's properties and attempting to copy the directory that it points to, but Thunar won't even allow me to highlight that line. Attempts to open the shortcut in a text editor have also failed, because Xubuntu assumes that what I want to open is what the shortcut points to rather than the shortcut itself.

Comment: I have Thunar running in Kali. No such option.  It is not a user friendly app

Comment: Linux ***DOES NOT HAVE "SHORTCUTS"***.  This is a specific file type interpreted by the windows explorer.exe.  Thunar has it's own version of it but I don't think that this is what you are looking at.  You are referring to a soft link/hard link/symlink.  In theory, programs ARE NOT SUPPOSED TO EVEN KNOW that you are not pointing at the actual file.  There is already a post on this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1312196/linux-symbolic-links-how-to-go-to-the-pointed-to-directory).

Comment: You might also try searching for "thunar resolve symlink" and see what pops up.